# MAC + git gui -> version conflict for package "Tcl": have 8.5.9, need 8.6

Tags: git, macos

I am getting this error when I click `git gui` from my terminal:

```
version conflict for package "Tcl": have 8.5.9, need 8.6
```

Can you help me to resolve this?  (using mac)

Comment: The issue I mention in my answer is closed (and fixed).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like [Homebrew/homebrew-core issue 49122](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/49122)

> On Mac 10.14, after my last brew update, latest git (2.5.0) fails when I run git gui:
>
> ```
> version conflict for package "Tcl": have 8.5.9, need 8.6
> ```
>
> I tried installing tcl-tk (which does install 8.6) but it didn't fix the issue, so I assume git doesn't use the version installed with brew.

Possible fix: [`Homebrew/homebrew-core` PR 49136](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/pull/49136)

> As a tcl-tk dependency for Git is not considered acceptable, this change
>   moves the `gitk` and `git-gui` tools to a new formula and sets the `NO_TCLTK`
>   flag when building Git.
>
> Additionally, this change ensures that we no longer install a `.app` for
>   `git-gui`.
>   Instead, we use the `homebrew-installed tcl-tk` wish binary to run
>   `git-gui` and `gitk`.

3 days later, [Mike McQuaid](https://github.com/MikeMcQuaid) just accepted a fix from [Alexander Richardson](https://github.com/arichardson), and the issue is now closed.

[`Homebrew/homebrew-core` commit dfa3ccf](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/commit/dfa3ccf1e7d3901e371b5140b935839ba9d8b706)

> ### `git-gui`: split from `git` formula.
>
> As a `tcl-tk` dependency for Git is not considered acceptable, this change moves the `gitk` and `git-gui` tools to a new formula and sets the `NO_TCLTK`
>   flag when building Git.
>
> Additionally, this change ensures that we no longer install a `.app` for `git-gui`.
>   Instead, we use the homebrew-installed `tcl-tk` wish binary to run `git-gui` and `gitk`.
>
> Without this change, all dialogs that are shown by git-gui are blank windows and can only be closed by memorizing the location of the buttons.

Comment: I need to brew reinstall git -s also then it works for me

Answer (score 4):

Installing ActiveState tcltk 8.6.9 and compiling from source solves it for me (MacOs 10.15):

```
brew reinstall git -s
```

Answer (score 0):

(Re)-install `tcl-tk` and `git-gui` from homebrew:

```
brew reinstall git-gui tcl-tk
```

For `tcl-tk` brew will show the following message:

> ````
> ==> Caveats
> tcl-tk is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into /usr/local,
> because macOS already provides this software and installing 
> another version in parallel can cause all kinds of trouble.
>
> If you need to have tcl-tk first in your PATH run:
> echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/tcl-tk/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc```
> ````

Follow the advice from `brew` and add the `export...` line to your `~/.zshrc` (or `~/.bashrc` if that's your default shell).

After you restart your shell `git-gui` should work as expected.